# UIScrollView with many UIImageViews - Memory management

Tags: ipad, memory-management, memory-leaks, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have this huge problem with memory management.

**The problem**:
I've got a `UIScrollView`, I've got an Array with 24 paths to Images in it and I want to show them in the `UIScrollView` with paging enabled.

All images is in the size 1024x748 (iPad landscape resolution with status bar) and the filetype is jpg or png.

I'm using *lazy loading* just to not exceed the memory when the `viewDidLoad`. And I'm going with the lazy load sample from Apple with the PageControl. Though I'm using `UIImageViews` instead of `UIViews`.

So my problem is that when I scroll to the third image, i want to remove the first image from the `UIScrollView` and release its memory. Because the further I scroll, more memory is draining. When I page in the UIScrollView and a new image is loaded and added, about 5000kb more memory is used, and when i step in to the `unloadPage:` (see below) nothing is released. Am I just "doing it wrong"?

How do I release and remove `UIImageViews` properly?

(I'm loading the UIImages with `initWithContentsOfFile:`)

**Here is my code**:

```
@interface SlideViewController : UIViewControllerExtended <UIScrollViewDelegate> {

    ScrollViewController *slider;
    IconView *currentChapter;
    NSMutableArray *chapters;
    NSMutableArray *views;
    UIImageView *controller;

}
```

**The lazy load function**:

```
- (void) loadImageToScrollView:(NSInteger)chapter withPage:(NSInteger)page {


    if (page < 0) return;
    if (page >= chapterCount) return;

    if([views objectAtIndex:page] != [NSNull null]) return;

    NSMutableArray *all = [[currentChapter getImages] copy];

    if(!([[all objectAtIndex:page] rangeOfString:@".mp4"].length > 0)) {
        controller = [views objectAtIndex:page];

        if((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null]) {

            NSArray *paths = [[all objectAtIndex:page] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

            NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[paths objectAtIndex:0]];
            NSString *ending = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[paths objectAtIndex:1]];

            NSString *file = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:ending]];

            UIImageView *tempImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(page * 1024, 0, 1024, 768)];
            UIImage *img = nil;
            img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:file];

            [tempImage setImage:img];
            [tempImage setTag:page];

            self.controller = tempImage;
            [tempImage release];

            [slider addSubview:controller];
            [views replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];

            [name release];
            [ending release];
            [file release];
        }

    }

    [all release];
}
```

**The unload view method** (which does not seem to work):

```
- (void) unloadPage: (int) page {
    if(page < 0) return;
    if(page >= chapterCount) return;
    if((NSNull *)[views objectAtIndex:page] != [NSNull null]) {
        UIImageView *viewToDelete = [views objectAtIndex:page];

        [viewToDelete removeFromSuperview];

        [views replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:[NSNull null]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is solved by watching the `#104` video session at [**WWDC2010**](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/). Which can be found on the [Apple Developer site](http://developer.apple.com/).

So if you have problem with memory leaks while loading big images, check it out. It's really, really useful.

Comment: The full name of the session is "Session 104 - Designing Apps with Scroll Views"

Answer (score 0):

[VSScrollview](https://github.com/iVishal/VSScroller.git) though I am late but for other users, I have made a class, VSScrollview, which reuses its views like UITableView reuses its cell. Its use is simple. Go through the readme in the link